# Div after iframe code hides unknowingly - Three column layout page

Tags: html, css

```css
 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    // 1st column Content Here
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
 //2nd column Content
 <iframe src="file.php" scrolling="no" style="height: 50px;width:100%; border:none; ></iframe>

  </div>
  
  
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    // 3rd column Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```

If i remove the iframe,the third column appears on right side but  if I add it then it doesn't appear.Please help me to solve this.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed a closing double quote after the iframe `style` tag. Add this, and it will work :)

Before:

```
<iframe src="file.php" scrolling="no" style="height: 50px;width:100%; border:none; ></iframe>
```

After:

```
<iframe src="file.php" scrolling="no" style="height: 50px;width:100%; border:none;"></iframe>
```

Notice the difference in colours with the syntax highlighting. If your development environment doesn't support this (or you hadn't noticed) it's well worth spending a bit of time getting one that does or getting used to it.

Comment: Thanks buddy...that was very silly mistake :) .Thank you for helping me to find out the problem.

Comment: Happens to us all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `"` missing

Add `padding: 10px 0;` instead of `padding: 10px;` to keep them in a line

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    // 1st column Content Here
  </div>


  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    //2nd column Content
    <iframe src="file.php" scrolling="no" style="height: 50px;width:100%; border:none;"></iframe>

  </div>


  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    // 3rd column Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**

Use flex like below

```css
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    // 1st column Content Here
  </div>


  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    //2nd column Content
    <iframe src="file.php" scrolling="no" style="height: 50px;width:100%; border:none;"></iframe>

  </div>


  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    // 3rd column Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```